# Is there a way to do a persistent multi-select in vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to create non-contiguous visual selections or persistent multi-select i.e. [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) in Vim?

Comment: What does it mean to link text ?

Comment: Do you mean [like this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_a_to-do_memo_file_with_links_as_in_Vim_help)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about non-contiguous visual selection.

Vim doesn't do that by default but [there seems to be a plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953) for that.

I haven't used it though.